# “App crashed” and 503 error response from Express hosted with Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm experiencing CORS errors **sometimes** when hosting my Node.js Express server on Heroku and trying to connect to it with a React app hosted on Netlify. I don't have any issues running locally (even though the front-end and backend are different URLs).

I'm getting:

> **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://[backend-heroku-url]' from origin 'https://[frontend-netlify-url]' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I'm using the 'cors' npm package that should allow everything by default.

### app.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const trackRoutes = require("./routes/trackRoutes");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use("/tracks", trackRoutes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const server = app.listen(port, () => {});
```

### trackRoutes.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");

router.all("*", cors());

const controller = require("../controllers/tracks");

router.get("/", cors(), controller.getTracks);

router.get("/download", cors(), controller.downloadTrack);

module.exports = router;
```

### trackController.js

```js
const { Track } = require("../db/db");

exports.getTracks = async (req, res, next) => {
  const results = await Track.findAll({ raw: true });
  res.status(201).json(results);
};

exports.downloadTrack = async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.query.id;
  const filePath = path.join(global.tempPath, id + ".mp3");
  blob.getBlobToLocalFile("tracks", id, filePath, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    try {
      res.download(filePath, () => {
        fs.unlink(filePath);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      fs.unlink(filePath);
    }
  });
};
```

## On the Client (React app)

```js
<a href='https://[backend-heroku-url]/tracks/download?id=123'>
```

On the client side, I'm just using using a link to hit the downloadTrack route, which **sometimes** works and downloads the file. Other times it throws the CORS error.

The Heroku logs have this in them as a result:

> at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/tracks/download?id=7b4013b0-9550-11e9-a752-9561bb97f681" request_id=fc3945e8-af23-4c05-a432-03601ba199b5 dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

After I get one error, then every request on the client that hits the backend will now throw a CORS error. The only way I can seem to make it start working again is to restart the Heroku server and it will work again until all the sudden it doesn't.

I'm clueless as to what else to try. I've thrown the cors() thing all over the place hoping it will help (I should only have to do it the one time with app.use(cors()) in app.js as far as I can tell). I guess my next step is to try hosting the node app on another service besides Heroku and see if it still does the same thing, which I'd really rather not do.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response when you get that error message? You can use the Network pane browser devtools to check. Is it a 503 or other 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response? The *App crashed* message shown in the logs, and the fact you need to restart the Heroku server to get a successful response again — those are indications that the actual problem you’re running into is that your Heroku application has stopped at the time you’re trying to send a request to it, and so the response being sent back is 5xx error.

Comment: The only reason you see that CORS message is because 5xx error responses will never include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. Consider the situation: Your app has crashed, so your application-set response headers aren’t going to get added to the response. So the real problem you need to solve is to figure out what’s causing your app to crash. And the cause has nothing at all to do with your CORS configuration.

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't consider it could have nothing to with CORS, but the browser just complained about CORS because it wasn't included in the response because of an unrelated error...

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, this seems to have been caused by a completely non-CORS related error as @sideshowbarker suggested.

Turns out fs.unlink() was running before the download actually finished, so the file was being deleted before the server was done reading from it. I guess this was  a race condition which is what made it so inconsistent.